# Laravel put foreach inside mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sendmail, swiftmailer

i want use a foreach inside my mail function, but i'm not sure how to do that, (i'm using swiftmailer, but that's not really relevant i think)

here is my code:

```
Mail::send('emails.bestelling',
        array(
            'mededeling' =>  $bestelcode,
            'rekeningnummer' => '000/000000/00',
            'naam'  => $userNaam,
            'totaal' => $totaal,
            'producten' =>  
            foreach ($mand as $rij) 
            {
                $rij->name;
                $rij->qty;
            }


        }


        ), function($message)
    {
        $message->from('noreply@test.be');
        $message->to('test@test.com', 'Admin')->subject('Creative Displays Bestelling');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach outside Mail() as below :

```
$production_string = '';
foreach ($mand as $rij) 
{
   $production_string .= "Name : ".$rij->name;
   $production_string .= ", Quantity : ".$rij->qty;
}

Mail::send('emails.bestelling',
        array(
            'mededeling' =>  $bestelcode,
            'rekeningnummer' => '000/000000/00',
            'naam'  => $userNaam,
            'totaal' => $totaal,
            'producten' =>  $production_string
        }
    ), function($message)
    {
        $message->from('noreply@test.be');
        $message->to('test@test.com', 'Admin')->subject('Creative Displays Bestelling');
    });
```

Comment: thanks! a little addition would be to make $production_string = '';
before the foreach otherwise he variable doesnt exist